# Snap store is having issues for Spotify. How to resolve?

Tags: snap, spotify

I am having an issue opening Spotify. Whenever, I type

```
spotify
```

in the terminal I get this message

```
snap-confine has elevated permissions and is not confined but should be. Refusing to continue to avoid permission escalation attacks
```

I then type in the terminal, the following commands,

```
sudo apt purge snapd snap-confine && sudo apt install -y snapd
```

Then I reinstall Spotify using `snap install spotify` This resolves the issue, but only temporarily because when I restart my device, the same issue occurs, and I have to do this process every time I restart. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: please check if there is more than 1 spotify snap installed `snap list | grep spotify`

Comment: Are you willing to [install from Spotify's repository](https://www.spotify.com/download/linux/), instead of as a Snap package?

Comment: @cmak.fr there is only one spotify installed.

Comment: @TomBrossman When I search for Spotify in the Ubuntu software repository, it says No Application Found